# Using Bind to a property from LitElement in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component, lit-element

I have a web component library built using litElement.  We are using these components in a React project and are running into an issue using some of the property binding attribute features.  React is throwing an error when using the below syntax.

Property binding examples can be seen here using

.attr="" and ?attr=""

https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/templates

Is there a way to use these property bindings inside a React app with a prefixed "." or "?". I am currently aware that we can use JSON.stringify to pass objects as a string to the attribute but would rather pass the objects as a property vs an attribute.

<my-cust-component .model="${this.someObj} ?mybool="false">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to use these property bindings inside a React app with a prefixed "." or "?"

Short answer: no.

The first reason is that those syntaxes are lit-specific constructs that you can only use in its rendering context (inside the template of the WebComponent). The other bad news is that React's *peculiar* view of DOM and rendering make it one of the most WC-incompatible frameworks: you'll have to rely on attributes and refs to communicate with your web components, no property and event binding.

https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/#react

Answer (score 0):

As someone already said you can't use lit-element syntaxes on the react file but you can listen to web components events in react if you use the wc-reactify lib (i'm using it on my project and works just fine), sometimes listening to events dispatched from the web component on your react application can be a solution.

https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/events
https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactify-wc